# Genus of cellular embedded graph

Tags: algebraic-topology, graph-theory

If I describe a surface of genus $g$ using a cellularly embedded graph with $n$ vertices, can I immediately conclude that $g = O(n)$ and thus the number of edges is linear in $n$? .

Also the other direction is not clear to me, for example every platonic solid is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere, but they have different number of vertices. 
So is there a theorem which states that if I have a surface of genus $g$ then I need at least $f(g)$ many vertices for a polygonal schema or a cellularly embedded graph to represent the surface ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

If $G$ is a planar graph with $v\ge 3$ vertices, it is well-known that $e \le 3v - 6$ (see Wikipedia's article on [planar graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph), for instance). For surfaces of higher genus, I don't know if a similar criterion exists, but you might try looking in Mohar and Thomassen's book $\textit{Graphs on Surfaces}$.

Comment: The general version of the relation for genus $g$ is that the number of edges is at most $3n + 6g - 6$ which is reached by any triangulation. For example, on the torus with $g=1$ ($\chi = 2 -2g = 0$), $K_7$ has $e=21$ and $n=7$.

Comment: The platonic solids have different girths (size of the smallest cycle/face) which is why they have different numbers of vertices. If the girth of the graph is $h$ then the number of edges in a graph on a surface of genus $g$ is at most the following: $$\frac{h}{h-2} (n+2g-2)$$

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean.  You can always contract a regular neighborhood of a spanning tree in your graph to get a $1$-vertex graph that fills up your surface, so I would say "no".  As for what kinds of degree sequences are allowed, I think this is still somewhat open, except for the torus.